# How to ensure source and build code is in sync in TypeScript project?

Tags: typescript, github, tsc

I am building a module in TypeScript and I host it on GitHub. I often work on the source files and every couple of days I transpile the project to `.js` files and push the build code to `dist/`.

What is the goto technique to achieve this automatically or to avoid that build code is out of sync with my TypeScript code?

So far I see GitHub workflows that build and push the build code after my commit a solution but I can't seem to find a workflow that is used across the TS landscape. I found [actions/typescript-build](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/typescript-build) but it doesn't seem to be widely used.

Or are Git hooks a better approach? Any hint is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do this.

You can have a script in your `package.json` file that compiles your code and have the script run before committing to git. Husky should be able to do that.

Comment: I fear it would be too easy to forget to commit them and they are eventually out of sync.